# Comparing array and get another array value on the selected array

Tags: c#, arrays

Please help me. I'm stuck on my array case. I'm newbie on this. Espesially to get array more than 2 variables. I had already browsing into google but i didn't got what i want, and now I've got stuck on it :(

I have array like this

```
string[] receive = receiveattachment.Split(new char[] { ',' });//{1,0,1,0}
string[] display = isdisplaytotal.Split(new char[] { ',' });//{1,1,1,0}
string[] ccTemp = cc.Split(new char[] { ',' });//{a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com, d@gmail.com}
```

First of all i got the same value from receive and display by this

```
foreach (var receive_ in receive)
                    {
                        foreach (var display_ in display)
                        {
                            if (receive_ == display_)
                            {
                              //do something
                            }
                        }
}
```

then my problem is, how to get a@gmail.com, c@gmail.com ?
I tried like this

```
 foreach (var receive_ in receive)
                        {
                            foreach (var display_ in display)
                            {
                                if (receive_ == display_)
                                {
                                    string[] ccTemp = cc.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                                    for (int i = 0; i < receive.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (receive[i] == "1")
                                        {
                                            if (_ccIsReceiveAndDisplay.Trim() != "") _ccIsReceiveAndDisplay += ",";
                                            _ccIsReceiveAndDisplay += ccTemp[i];
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (_ccIsReceiveAndDisplay.Trim() != "") _ccIsReceiveAndDisplay += ",";
                                            _ccIsReceiveAndDisplay += ccTemp[i];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    }
```

but it will got only receive = 1 value. not receive 1 and display =1

Comment: Your code seems to have some problems. You have `var getThesamevalue;` but NO assignment at all, no value set, nothing! The loops are useless there.

Comment: Also, it does NOT matter what you do in that receive/display for to get the values, if you have the same values in first and second array ({1,0,1,0,0,0,1} and {0,0,0,0,0,1,0}), because it will search the entire array for matching values, **all** your values will be printed because this has no logic to compare or edit or match at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the arrays are the same length, use `for` and an index.

Like this:

```
for (var index=0; index<receive.length; index++)
    if (receive[index] == "1" && display[index] == "1")
        DoSomethingWithEmail( ccTemp[index] )
```

This is also faster, because it loops through the array only once, not once per element in the array.

As a bonus, get the emails the linq-way:

`receive.Zip(display, (a,b) => new {A=a, B=b}).Zip(ccTemp, (ab,c) => new {use=ab.A=="1"&&ab.B=="1", email=c}).Where( x=> x.use ).Select( x => x.email)`